# Who/How/When creates the app.browser.module.ts file in Angular with SSR?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-module

Recently, I have been seeing different Angular projects with SSR and I have noticed that in most of them there is a file called `app.browser.module.ts` and also an `app.server.ts` and `app.module.ts`.

As I've been testing in my own projects, adding Angular Universal simply creates `app.server.module.ts`. The question is the following: `app.browser.module.ts` is created automatically somehow by the Angular Universal schematics or must it be created manually?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The default angular universal schematics does not create this file. Were these projects using `@ng-toolkit/universal`  maybe?

Comment: I think the same. Probably yes. It is probably that they use the `@ng-toolkit/universal` starter.  I wasn't sure if universal angular automatically creates it. Thank you!